# cannot insert into a non-nullable column with default value via UDT

Tags: c#, sql

Sorry, I don't know how to properly describe my issue in a simple and clear way. I pasted a simplified version of my code and hopefully it explains well.

I have a table that has a non-nullable column with default value:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DemoTable] (
...
[DemoColumn] [varchar](200) NOT NULL DEFAULT('None')
...
)
```

and there is a proc that updates DemoTable via a UDT `UDT_Demo`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_Update_DemoTable
    @demoUDT UDT_Demo READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE DemoTable
    USING @demoUDT
    ON ...
    WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE
    SET ...
        DemoTable.DemoColumn = @demoUDT.DemoColumn,
        ...
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN　INSERT
    (... DemoColumn ... ) VALUES (... @demoUDT.DemoColumn ...)
END
```

The UDT_Demo is defined as:

```
CREATE TYPE UDT_Demo AS TABLE
(
...
[DemoColumn] [varchar](200) NULL
...
)
```

The following is how I call the proc `pr_Update_DemoTable` in C# code:

```
DataTable udt_Demo = new DataTable();
...
udt_Demo.Columns.Add("DemoColumn");
...
udt_Demo.Rows.Add(new object[] { ... demoColumnValue ... }); // demoColumnValue is null in this case

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("pr_Update_DemoTable");
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("demoUDT", udt_Demo);
... // some addtional logic to prepare for the execution
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This code will give exception "cannot insert NULL into DemoTable.DemoColumn because DemoColumn is not nullable"

=======other approaches I've tried======

approach 1:

If I modified the UDT_Demo definition to

```
CREATE TYPE UDT_Demo AS TABLE
(
...
[DemoColumn] [varchar](200) NOT NULL DEFAULT('None')
...
)
```

The the exception message would become "cannot insert NULL into UDT_Demo.DemoColumn because DemoColumn is not nullable"

approach 2:

If I don't specify the DemoColumn value in the C# code, then I get the exception "number of values inserted doesn't match the number of columns in the table"

approach 3:

This is currently working but is not ideal. I don't want to hardcode the default value.

```
DataTable udt_Demo = new DataTable();
...
udt_Demo.Columns.Add("UDTColumn");
...
udt_Demo.Rows.Add(new object[] { ... demoColumnValue ?? "None" ... });
... // the rest of the code is the same
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want SQL to use the default value you should not declare the column in the insert statement.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testDefault](
[col1] [int] NULL,
[col2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[col3] [nchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[testDefault] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_testDefault_col3]  DEFAULT ('test') FOR [col3]
```

inserting data

```
INSERT INTO testDefault
(col1, col2)
VALUES(1, 'TEST') -- not declaring col3
```

select from the table

```
SELECT * FROM testDefault
```

will give you the result

```
col1    col2        col3
1       TEST        test
```

Comment: I know this, but it doesn't help my issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can update `pr_Update_DemoTable` procedure by setting `DemoColumn` value using

```
IFNULL(@demoUDT.DemoColumn, 'None')
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is essentially the same solution as my Approach 3, right? The hardcoded 'None' appears in 2 places, one in the table creation script, and one in the proc definition script. Ideally we want a hardcoded string appears only in 1 place.